# Secure way of granting access to production database

Tags: windows-server-2008, security, sql-server

We are currently using the FedEx Ship Manager in our warehouse and would like to automate the process of entering customer shipping information automatically. Inside the ship manager there is an option of connecting to a database via ODBC and looking up the customer information based on a unique key. I have tested this method with our development database and it works wonderfully.

However the problem is that this will need to be querying against the production database to retrieve the information we need. The production database sits inside of a VPN. The VPN also contains several other things such as our development servers, phone servers, etc. and is only accessible from a couple IPs. We want to lock it down as much as possible so what we have come up with is:

- Create a View that contains only the information necessary for FedEx software
- Create a user that only has SELECT privileges on that view.
- Ensure the database is only accessible by connecting to our VPN.

This seems to me a very secure way of doing what we need but I am wondering if anyone sees a glaring hole in our intended plan? Possibly a better way of doing what we are looking for.

If it matters we are using SQL-Server as our database, PPTP as our VPN and the entire infrastructure resides inside of AWS.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, this would also mean adding the Ship Manager server to the VPN, right? If this is all it needs the VPN for, you can secure things further by configuring the VPN server's firewall to only whitelist packets from the Ship Manager server if they're part of ESTABLISHED,RELATED connections, or if their destination is the database server's listening TCP port.

Comment: The Ship Manager software will reside on a desktop computer in the warehouse. The desktop would "dial in" to the VPN so that it can gain access to the database server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LGTM. However, keep in mind that any permissions granted to the public role will also be granted to this user. So if it would be a serious violation to have this user gain access to the base table (or other objects in the db), you'll need to audit this periodically.